# Calculating the core of a game

Tags: game-theory

In a coalitional game n miners find equal blocks of gold. Two can carry one piece home. The payoff of a coalition S is $\nu(S)=|S|/2$ if $|S|$ even and $(|S|-1)/2$ for $|S|$ odd.

Determine the core if n is even, that is the set of imputations $x$ such that $\sum_{i\in S}x_i\ge \nu(S)$ for all S.

Could someone show how to do this systematically? What if three miners can carry one lump?

Answer (score -1):

If the cardinal of the grand coalition is odd, the core is empty because it is impossible to share an amount $v(N)$ such that $\forall i \in N$, the sum of the payoff of the players belonging to $v(N\setminus i)$ receive more than $v(N)=v(N\setminus i)$.

If the cardinal of the grand coalition is even, then it is easy to see that $x_i=\frac{1}{2}$ $\forall i \in N$ belongs to the core and it is the only one possible payoff.